# Sitefinity one username for multiple user

Tags: sitefinity-5

To Whom it may concern

I would just like to know is possible to use one user name and it be used by multiple users at the same time on sitefinity without it kicking out a logged on user when another another user logs in using the same user name.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has a backend role then he will not be able to login concurrently from different machines/browsers. He will have to terminate the existing session before starting a new one.

Frontend users do not have this limitation.

Comment: these front-end credentials and back-end credentials are totally different from each other.